# US citizen overstayed for 11 months in Philippines

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, overstaying, philippines

My boyfriend overstayed here for 11 months. I was just asking if he can go back here again after paying fines?

Answer (score 9):

Highly unlikely. According to [How much are the Penalties for Overstaying as a Tourist in the Philippines?](http://www.in-philippines.com/how-much-are-the-penalties-for-overstaying-as-a-tourist-in-the-philippines/?fdx_switcher=true) he’d be best to leave immediately - leaving aside the fine, overstaying for 12 months or more means he’d be referred for deportation. Having that as a black mark on his travel history would probably haunt any future travel plans for a long time.

Comment: ...any future travel plans to *anywhere*, not just the Philippines.